# How to add objects to a array with a API URL that is inside a API?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I have the code bellow:

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import NavigationBar from "../../Components/NavigationBar/NavigationBar";
import PokemonCard from "../../Components/PokemonCard/PokemonCard";
// import { Container } from './styles';
import api from "../../config/api";

export default class Listagem extends Component {
  constructor(){
    super()
    this.state = {
      pokemons: []
    };
  }
  
  

   async componentDidMount() {
    //Popula array de Pokemons
      await api.get("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon").then(res => {
      const pokemonsArray = res.data.results;
      const pokemonData = [];
      //Vai dentro do array e busca informações que estão na URL do objeto
      pokemonsArray.forEach(pokemon => {
         api.get(pokemon.url).then(res => {
          pokemonData.push({
            name: res.data.name,
            moves: res.data.moves,
            types: res.data.types,
            image: res.data.sprites.front_default
          });
        });
      });
      // console.log(res)
      this.setState({ pokemons: pokemonData });
      // console.log(this.state.pokemons)
    });
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.pokemons)
    return ( 
      <div>
        <NavigationBar />
        {this.state.pokemons.map(pokemon => (
          <PokemonCard pokemon={pokemon} />
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I'm trying to fetch the data from the URL that is inside the api.get but i don't know how to change the state with the data that is returning.

When i try to console log the "this.state.pokemons" i'm getting 2 arrays. One empty and the other with the data that i need. So i'm not being able to render the component.[This is the output on the chrome console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2p7d1.png)

Thank's in advance. This is probably a dumb question but i'm stuck in this all day.

Comment: The first print is the initial render. The second one is when fetch is already done.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should also add `async/await` for your inner API calls so that you will get data in `pokemonData` array,

```
pokemonsArray.forEach(async pokemon => {
     await api.get(pokemon.url).then(res => {
       pokemonData.push({
          name: res.data.name,
          moves: res.data.moves,
          types: res.data.types,
          image: res.data.sprites.front_default
       });
     });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED:

I put the setState inside the "forEach" loop so he returned the full array first. Probably not the best solution but it worked for me.